# D3 Axis ticks hard count

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

Is there a way for the count argument to .ticks() to be a hard value that is to be adhered to exactly instead of a hint? There are some cases where this formatting is really something that you want to have.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the function [`.tickValues()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickValues) to set the tick values explicitly. If called with no arguments, it returns the current tick values -- this would allow you to check how many there are and add/remove/recalculate as needed.

Comment: But .tickValues() returns null if called outside of a .call() and it is not really clear how to call it from within.

Comment: Though now I found this example by mbostock that does a good job of explaining it: http://bl.ocks.org/2996785